# Will screed on plywood do instead of beam and block, to replace a floor?

Tags: structural-engineering, concrete, construction-management

I'm gutting and redoing an older house (early 20th C, ordinary suburban terrace house, London UK).

I'd planned beam and (dense) block for the upstairs structural floor, for a few reasons, and already got structural calculations for load spreading on the old foundations for the extra load this would involve.

The beams would be supported on engineering brick in some places, or on the stiffened flanges of 203x203x46kg beams across openings.

The planned floor above would then be neoprene pads with battens resting on them, and floorboards on those (for a nice effect and also ensures space for services and exceptional acoustic isolation - almost "box within box" by design, stopping most vibration through floors and around through the terrace walls). The wider design takes care of acoustic isolation of the walls which isn't relevant here.

My reasons are a bit diverse, in no special order - beam and block guarantees no squeaking underfoot, guarantees very high quality acoustic resilience, excellent fireproofing, and makes it dead easy to support a wide (4m) span or to support battening anywhere needed. Also it's quick,cheap, and easy, no pump either, just some heavy lifting.  I know this is probably way way overkill, but I'm comfortable with that and don't consider it a factor in any decision.

The final, and perhaps most important, reason is that the building is space challenged. By which I mean, I'm fighting for every vertical cm I can save on the underfloor thickness. Every cm is a cm less of ceiling height, and also either a steeper or a larger stairwell. I can afford a couple of cm thicker for the 1st floor structure, but more than about 5-8cm would really hurt due to knock-on effects. Beam and block gets my structural floor thickness down to 150mm and nothing else except steel can do that, and I need that space badly.

So I had this all sorted out. But the job got passed to a different engineer in the same company, and he's urging a different design - engineering wood beams with 22mm plywood and 60-80mm of poured screed with mesh.

His reason is load and age. He agrees the original plan will be fine, and the work done on walls and load spreading will be ample to accommodate the extra weight both within the walls and on the original foundations, but from what I can gather its a feeling that the building was originally designed for timber floors and just wasn't designed to have this kind of extra load or structure. He also cites building cost but I think that's more like a carrot dangling on a string - its a nice thing but in the scheme of things any cost difference will be tiny and I discount it.

He agrees that screed (1800kg/m3) and full-on concrete (2400 kg/m3) are similar enough density to use the latter instead of screed if I wanted, and I feel slightly pressured, although if I say no, it will be no.

Apart from considering whether or not to accede to his desire to lighten the load, my other more serious issue is that the depth would go up a lot. The original plan's depth would be 150mm floor beams, plus pads, battens and flooring. A version done as he suggests would be 200mm engineering timber beam, 20-25mm plywood, and 60-80mm screed/concrete for a total of almost 300mm - almost 150mm more... and all to save at most 110kg/m3 (beam = 250kg/m3 max, 75mm screed = 135kg/m3 min) that we've already calculated our way around anyhow. It's just not worth it as far as I can see.

Before I say no, is there anything important here **from a purely structural engineering, rather than general home improvement, perspective** that I might be missing or need to take into account, when I consider this new option against the existing one they have presented?

Comment: Better asked on the Home Improvement stack...

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, but on reflection, it's really an engineering question. From a structural engineering perspective, is what I mean. Edited last sentence  to clarify

Comment: Didn't you say this engineer had already stated your original design was structurally sound?  If so, go with the aesthetic choice.

Comment: Its a different engineer in the company, I'm likely, but before going against the current suggestion/advice I'd like to be sure if there is a structural consideration that I'm not seeing here?